# prerender.io not rendering the same HTML as actual AngularJS SPA

Tags: angularjs, prerender

I have an AngularJS SPA, and if I load a particular state it works fine (e.g http://www.localhosttest.com/en/products/).  If however I pass through prerender.io server, e.g (http://localhost:3000/http://www.localhosttest.com/en/products/), the page will not render completely as if not all javascript code has executed.

However, it is definitely not an issue of not enough time to render.  To eliminate that factor, I have increased the `JS_TIMEOUT` to 90,000ms. Also, on page load I set `window.prerenderReady = false;`.  Then, I did a `setTimeout()` which will set it to `true` after 60,000ms.  This gives it 60 seconds to render, which is more than enough time.

Is it possible to somehow log the console output, for the request done from the prerender.io server?  This way I can know if maybe some exception is stopping it from rendering.

Comment: You can enable the logger() plugin in the server.js file and that will show any output like errors when rendering the page.

Comment: @Prerender.io how do you enable the logger() plugin? I couldn't find any documentation about it.

Comment: Just uncomment that line in the server.js file for the logger plugin. Email me if you need more help with that. todd@prerender.io